# Powershell Test-Path fails to find registry entry

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check the registry for the lookback check flag thus:

```
Test-Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck
```

This always returns `$false` when in fact the value does actually exist.  I've tried `-PathType leaf` and `-PathType Any` with the same result.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't DisableLoobackCheck a property of HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa?

You can test-path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa to see if that path exists, but you need to use Get-ItemProperty to inspect the properties the Lsa key.

[I think this Test-PathReg script does what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/candede/test-registry-paths).

Comment: I tried Get-ItemProperty and that also failed but the linked script works wonderfully.  Thanks!!!